# How can I increase stored procedure performance with multiple if else statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with multiple `if-elseif- else` statements. When I try to remove this `if elseif` statement and execute only single portion of that query, it returns results very fast, but when use this query with multiple another queries using `if-elseif` case statement, then it takes too much time...

For example:

```
if @Status = 1
begin
    select .....
end
else if @Status = 2
begin
    select .....
end
else if @Status = 3
begin
    select .....
end
else if....
```

There are many more `else if` statements in this stored procedure..

Comment: Please provide context of the code so that we can understand and help with how to aggregate/replace the if else. Anyways, you can use decode/case if the select statements are similar.

Comment: I re-tagged the question with `sql-server` based on the syntax used in the question.

Comment: Using  IFs is only going to harm performance. Post the individual `SELECT` statements and try to rewrite them so you *don't* need that IF. Add proper indexes. It's impossible to help more without the actual queries

Comment: No one can help you improve code that cannot be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may be in some "don't do this" books, you can try to create a stored procedure for each `status` value and call it directly by building a dynamic TSQL statement (`"exec yourproc_" + statusValue`).

```
create proc youproc_1 as 
begin
select your_data_for_status1;
end;

create proc youproc_2 as 
begin
select your_data_for_status2;
end;
```

etc...

Comment: I have 32 different Status so it's not possible to create 32 Storedprocedure.. thanks...